# Hand cursor on disabled fields

Tags: html, css

I am working with html input text field and i want to force the cursor to be a hand when i hover on the text field. The text field is readonly so a cancel symbol (circle with diagonal slash) shows on hover. Am using

css class on the field but its not

```
.rdonly
{
cursor: hand;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

in template

```
<input type= "text" readonly class="rdonly"/>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try :

```
.rdonly:hover
{
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GJ4TS/

The thing is, when I try your code in jsfiddle, it works...

Answer (score 3):

I know it's an old thread but still I'll answer it as the correct solution should be by adding `[readonly]`:

```
input[readonly]
{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```